# recurse over a list

Tags: python, recursion

I'm trying to recurse over a list (eg. [True, [[True, False], [False, [False, True]]]]) using Python.  I know that the list length will always be 2 and both values will be boolean.  I'd like to take those values and substitute them back into the list until there are only 2 values left (or 1 boolean value).  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: How do you want to combine the values?  Is this homework?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't said how to combine the two parts, so I'm assuming `or` but you could use another function instead.

```
l = [True, [[True, False], [False, [False, True]]]]

def foo(x):
    if isinstance(x, list):
        return foo(x[0]) or foo(x[1])
    else:
        return x

print foo(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

say your list is `l`

```
def print_list(list):
   t = type(list())
   for item in list:
      if type(item) is t:
         print_list(item)
      else:
         print item
 print_list(l)
```

Something simple like that would print every item in your list.

Comment: `type(list())` is spelled "`list`".

Comment: true. Spelling it out for the new guy.

Comment: Well, not exactly spelled list, because in this case Jweede is shadowing the builtin list. So unless the argument passed in happens to be callable, what you're going to get with this is an exception. I'd recommend not using list as the argument to your function ;)

Comment: yeah. The `isinstance` method was a much better choice.